# C# Creating and passing strings between voids Console Application

Tags: c#, console-application

This is what I have

```
public static string allRecordsFound = "";

static void parseRecords()
{

// do all my work here
allRecordsFound = "sadsda"; //this is whats this static void creats  
}

static void doMoreWork()
{
string[] splitRecords = allRecordsFound.Split('\n');

}
```

I'm just not positive how to reset the public static string so after the void that finds the data can pass it throughout the whole Console app.

Thanks!

Comment: why do you not have any parameters or return values?

Comment: no one will ever know what you want, please give more details, what does it mean reset (change its value to previous one), pass it through whole app, static variable is always present, you can access it by MyClass::variable ... add details pls

Comment: This question just resembles a *really* good reason why you should never use static variables to pass data between methods.

Comment: I real answer is i dont know how, so i'm looking for an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First option would be adding a parameter to `doMoreWork()` so it will become `doMoreWork(string records)`.

If you insist using `static` variables for passing parameters or the application is multi-threaded then you can use a `Queue` instead. First method puts records into queue and second one gets them. If there are more than one thread acessing the queue then use `ConcurrentQueue` which is available in .NET 4.0